# “Matrix4 entries must be finite” when running integration test with package "integration_test"

Tags: flutter

The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:

```
Matrix4 entries must be finite.
'dart:ui/painting.dart':
Failed assertion: line 50 pos 10: '<optimized out>'

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      _matrix4IsValid (dart:ui/painting.dart:50:10)
#3      SceneBuilder.pushTransform (dart:ui/compositing.dart:301:12)
#4      TransformLayer.addToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:1677:27)
#5      ContainerLayer.buildScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:938:5)
#6      RenderView.compositeFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:228:37)
#7      RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:508:18)
#8      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:892:13)
#9      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:370:5)
#10     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1146:15)
#11     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1083:9)
#12     LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1546:13)
#13     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:864:7)
(elided 17 frames from class _AssertionError, class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, dart:async-patch, and package:stack_trace)
```

Comment: This usually happens when there is an exception thrown before you call runApp(); Do you maybe have some async initialization running which might fail on integration tests?

Answer (score 1):

when your device(mobile) screen is OFF it happens, increase screen timeout from display settings (android)

Comment: This also happens when you have another app on-screen/active instead of the one you're running your tests against.